# Performance comparison between in-place vs out-of-pace matrix transposition

Tags: performance, matrix, transpose, in-place

[Wikipedia has an extensive summary of methods for in-place matrix transposition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition)

These methods look hard to implement, before committing to implementing them I'm wondering if there are any benchmarks or other evidence that would say these techniques outperform out-of-place matrix transposition in terms of walltime (on CPU/GPU/ any architecture)?

Do they all run slower compared to using an out-of-place transpose where the data is copied to a different destination?

Comment: No, "Accessor Transpose" just hands the problem off to the next step of the computation, making it potentially free.  (e.g. there are matmul algorithms to handle the case where both matrices are stored the same way, but it's significantly easier if one input has sequential columns and the other has sequential rows, in flat memory order.)  Other than that, I'd look at some library implementations, like Eigen probably has a SIMD transpose for x86 at least.  You didn't say what CPU architectures you care about, or what problem size relative to L1d cache size, etc.

Comment: @PeterCordes For example, Eigen does out of place

Answer (score 2):

In short, I don't think I have ever seen an in-place exchange being faster than out of place. Just think about "when did you last chose an in-place sort instead of the out of place version".

But the reason to use in-place is usually memory considerations or allocation considerations. In which case you are bound to use it.

For an out of place exchange, you also have to think about cache, cache and cache, subdivide your problem into smaller parts until both target and source can comfortably be in the cache at the same time.